# Trouble accessing folders with SSH in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Over the last week, I've been experiencing trouble with opening folders in VSCode when remotely connected to a machine using SSH. This is strange as I'm working on two remote machines and this issue only occurs on one of them.

The machine I have VSCode installed on is running Windows 10. I'm connecting to two different Linux machines:

- Machine 1: Running on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) - SSH connection and operations work fine.
- Machine 2: Running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.3 - SSH connection works, but opening folders prompts repeated password requests even with the correct password.

When I try to enter my password to open the remote folder on Machine 2, I get the following output which repeats indefinitely:

```
[10:40:24.388] > Password:
[10:40:24.477] "install" terminal command done
[10:40:24.477] Install terminal quit with output:
[10:40:24.560] > Password:
```

I've tried several methods to resolve this issue, including:

- Deleting the `.vscode-server` directory on the second machine through SSH
- Deleting the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\` directory
- Uninstalling VSCode and reinstalling it
- Toggling the `remote.SSH.useLocalServer` configuration in different ways

None of these methods have worked so far. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Did you try restarting the SSH server(daemon) on the remote machine 2?